# Extension Amazon SNS 2.0.0 doesn't work on CiviCRM 5.69.2

Tags: extension

I'm sorry to report that there is an error in Extension Amazon SNS 2.0.0 after upgrading to CiviCRM 5.69.2. Unfortunately I can't get an error log but Wordpress gives me an error page when I want to access to the extension administration page. The only way is to rename the extension folder, but then I can't disable it.

With the php error log:

```
[18-Jan-2024 09:53:33 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface::MAJOR_VERSION in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Utils::defaultUserAgent()
#1 /home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/civicrm-aws-sns-sms-2.0.0/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(194): GuzzleHttp\default_user_agent()
#2 /home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/civicrm-aws-sns-sms-2.0.0/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Client->configureDefaults()
#3 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(61): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct()
#4 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(216): CRM_Extension_Browser->getGuzzleClient()
#5 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(194): CRM_Extension_Browser->grabRemoteJson()
#6 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(173): CRM_Extension_Browser->grabCachedJson()
#7 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(138): CRM_Extension_Browser->_discoverRemote()
#8 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(239): CRM_Extension_Browser->getExtensions()
#9 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(43): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->formatRemoteExtensionRows()
#10 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(719): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->preProcess()
#11 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(76): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#12 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform()
#13 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
#14 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
#15 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(364): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#16 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(170): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit()
#17 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(110): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#18 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(322): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run()
#19 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#20 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#21 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#22 /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#23 /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#24 /home/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#25 /home/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#26 {main}
  thrown in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 116
[18-Jan-2024 09:53:38 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface::MAJOR_VERSION in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php:116
Stack trace:
#0 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Utils::defaultUserAgent()
#1 /home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/civicrm-aws-sns-sms-2.0.0/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(194): GuzzleHttp\default_user_agent()
#2 /home/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/civicrm-aws-sns-sms-2.0.0/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Client->configureDefaults()
#3 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(61): GuzzleHttp\Client->__construct()
#4 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(216): CRM_Extension_Browser->getGuzzleClient()
#5 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(194): CRM_Extension_Browser->grabRemoteJson()
#6 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(173): CRM_Extension_Browser->grabCachedJson()
#7 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Browser.php(138): CRM_Extension_Browser->_discoverRemote()
#8 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(239): CRM_Extension_Browser->getExtensions()
#9 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(138): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->formatRemoteExtensionRows()
#10 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(174): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->browse()
#11 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(110): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#12 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(322): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run()
#13 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#14 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#15 /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1231): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#16 /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#17 /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#18 /home/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#19 /home/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#20 {main}
  thrown in /home/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Utils.php on line 116
```

I tried with composer install in the extension folder and there are nothing to install, update or remove

Comment: I'll edit my question with more solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Without the exact text of the error message, it's difficult to know the exact cause.  You may want to check your PHP logs (on a Debian server, this would be `/var/log/php8.1.log` for PHP 8.1).

However, you can most likely resolve the problem by running `composer install` inside the extension folder.  Amazon SNS requires the Guzzle library, and was packaged with Guzzle 6.  However, you very likely have a plugin that was packaged with Guzzle 7.  If you run `composer update` then Amazon SNS should get Guzzle 7 and the problem should go away.

**UPDATE** First - I meant `composer update`, not `composer install` - hopefully that fixes your problem!

But if not - your logs make clear that you have multiple Guzzles on different versions.

**Find your Guzzles**: Search for a `CHANGELOG.md` file in a `guzzle` folder.  Open each changelog and check the version.  At least one will be version 6, at least one will be version 7.

**Fix the Guzzle 6 versions**: If you're lucky, the ones with version 6 will have a `composer.json` and you can run `composer update`.  If not, you will probably need to open an issue with the author of that plugin/extension/etc.